# Algorithm for multiple string replacement by index

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, replace, text-formatting

I have some problems thinking up a good algorithm to replace some entities in a text. Here are the details:
I have a text that I need to format to html, information about the formatting is in a python list containing dictionaries of entities. Let's say for example that the original text was like this(please, pay attention to the formatting):

**Lorem Ipsum** is simply *dummy* text of the [printing](http://google.com) and typesetting industry.

The text I will get will be this (without formatting):

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

and a list of entities like this:

```
entities = [{"entity_text":"Lorem Ipsum", "type": "bold", "offset": 0, "length":"11"}, {"entity_text":"dummy", "type": "italic", "offset": 22, "length":"5"},{"entity_text":"printing", "type": "text_link", "offset": 41, "length":"8", "url": "google.com"}]
```

My algorithm should translate the given unformatted text and entities into this html:

```html
<b>Lorem Ipsum</b> is simply <i>dummy</i> text of the <a href="google.com">printing</a> and typesetting industry
```

So that it can be compiled into the original message.
I have tried string replacement but it messes up the offset(position of the entities from the start of the text). And remember that there could be many of those words with formatting in the text, that are not formatted, so I have to find exactly the ones that should be formatted. Any help from anyone? I'm writing the code in python but you can specify the algorithm in any language

**EDIT**
sorry I forgot to post the code that I have tried. This is it:

```
format_html(text, entities):
    for entity in entities:
        try:
            entity_text = entity['entity_text']
            position = text.find(entity_text, entity['offset'])
            if position == entity['offset']:
                before = text[:position]
                after = text[min(position+entity['length'], len(text)-1):]
                if entity['type'] == 'text_link':
                    text_link = '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(entity['url'], entity_text)
                    text = before + text_link + after
                elif entity['type'] == 'code':
                    code = '<code>{}</code>'.format(entity_text)
                    text = before + code + after
                elif entity['type'] == 'bold':
                    bold_text = '<b>{}</b>'.format(entity_text)
                    text = before + bold_text + after
                elif entity['type'] == 'italic':
                    italic_text = '<i>{}</i>'.format(entity_text)
                    text = before + italic_text + after
                elif entity['type'] == 'pre':
                    pre_code = '<pre>{}</pre>'.format(entity_text)
                    text = before + pre_code + after
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: What algorithm have *you* tried? Please post the code here.

Comment: @not_a_robot, please check the edit

Comment: What does `get_message` and `parse_entity` look like? Could you please include that class and all of the relevant code? *You* may have be familiar with your classes, but we aren't!

Comment: @not_a_robot, done, I excluded the classes and used the format I presented in the question

Comment: What is `text`? What's going on in the line `position = text.find(entity_text, entity['offset'])`?

Comment: `text` is the unformatted text given. the line `position = text.find(entity_text, entity['offset'])` finds the starting position of the first occurrence of the the 'entity_text' starting from the offset given. Then it compares it to the offset to make sure that it actually starts from the offset. I do this, because of encoding issues(multiple languages can be in the text). If it is not well decoded by python, then the offset and position will be different and I will not bother formatting the text. For now, just consider that position is the same as offset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132923/discussion-between-ken-and-not-a-robot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was how I solved it. I adjusted the offsets with the lenght of extra strings added to the text (because of the tags) each time I modified the text. This is costly in terms of computational time, but that is the only option I've seen yet

```
def format_html(text, entities):
    for entity in entities:
        try:
            modified = None
            entity_text = entity['entity_text']
            position = text.find(entity_text, entity['offset'])
            if position == entity['offset']:
                before = text[:position]
                after = text[min(position+entity['length'], len(text)-1):]
                if entity['type'] == 'text_link':
                    text_link = '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(entity['url'], entity_text)
                    text = before + text_link + after
                    modified = 15 + len(entity['url'])
                elif entity['type'] == 'code':
                    code = '<code>{}</code>'.format(entity_text)
                    text = before + code + after
                    modified = 13
                elif entity['type'] == 'bold':
                    bold_text = '<b>{}</b>'.format(entity_text)
                    text = before + bold_text + after
                    modified = 7
                elif entity['type'] == 'italic':
                    italic_text = '<i>{}</i>'.format(entity_text)
                    text = before + italic_text + after
                    modified = 7
                elif entity['type'] == 'pre':
                    pre_code = '<pre>{}</pre>'.format(entity_text)
                    text = before + pre_code + after
                    modified = 11
               if modified:
                   for other in entites:
                       if other['offset'] > entity.offset:   
                           other.offset += modified
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Do you thing this code works when there are repetitions with different types, e.g. same *word* in bold and same **word** in italic? and what about when the offset are not ordered?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really pay attention to a word having 2 or more formatting, I guess this algorithm won't work that way. As for the order of the offsets, it does not matter because we only shift offsets that are greater than the offset of the current entity. Check the line  `if other['offset'] > entity.offset:`

Comment: Updating the offsets a posteriori is a good idea but more complex than the problem requieres. In addition, you can create an easier code if you control the modified with the len() function and do a generic `text = before + specific_text + after` being the specific_text the specific part of code in each case.

Comment: Another improvement that you can do is to use the exact offsets to extract the correct entity instead of find method as `position = text.find(entity_text, entity['offset'])`, thus you can deal with the repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

You might mean something like this?

```
text = ""
for entry in entries:
    line = ""
    for key, value in entry.iteritems():
        if key == 'entity_text':
            line += value
        elif key == 'type' and value == 'bold':
            line = "<b> {} </b>".format(line)
        elif key == 'type' and value == 'italic':
            line = "<i> {} </i>".format(line)
        elif key == 'type' and value == 'text_link':
            line = '<a href="google.com">{}</a>'.format(line)
    text += line
text
```

Translates to

```
'<b> Lorem Ipsum </b><i> dummy </i><a href="google.com">printing</a>'
```

Comment: sorry, I think I was wrong not to have posted the whole method. `text` is actually the text given, the plain one. You have to find the words to format in the variable `text`. In this case `text` is "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.". The problem is, how would you know the positions in the text to add them. As you can see, your result gives a different text from the original

Comment: I see, i guess it really depends on the data you start off with, what that is is still unclear to me. Is it a website's code, or filecontent..

Comment: It's not a website and I really don't get how that information is needed here though. I'm given a string (unformatted) and a variable `entities` containing information about which words in which positions need to be formatted in what ways(Like the example I gave in the question). I just need to provide a html output with the correct formatting of the text given

Comment: if you have the position of the word inside of a string object, maybe you could use the replace function;
>>> s = 'hello there'

>>> s.replace(s[0:4], 'heaven')
'heaveno there'

Comment: definitely that's the first thing that would come to anyone's mind, but after replacing the first entity, the offset of the others will no longer be correct,  which is the main problem I have. Try reading my code. I've already done something similar